# Change screen resolution without monitor under Linux?

Tags: linux, resolution, xorg, c++, xrandr

I got a GUI program which will be executed along the OS (`CentOS 6.6`) boots.

The resolution configuration is programmed in the `init` part of the GUI program, my solution right now is get the resolution sets of the monitor using `xrandr` and parse the result and set it to one of the candidates, you can choose one of them in the `Preferences` part of the GUI program later. But `xrandr` won't work if no monitor is plugged in, right?

If I got no monitor plugged into the box, that means I have no idea what the resolution sets one monitor can provide (at least not from `xrandr`), so now what I want is, if I turn on the computer, and the GUI program will be executed, after plugging a monitor later, I can see the GUI program already loaded in the monitor.

I mean I want the resolution fixed (`1152x864 75.0Hz`, for example) in the GUI program init part using some commands or APIs if no monitor plugged?

Does anyone know anything about the available `commands` or `APIs`?